# laravel passe array from controller to view undefined

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

i am new to laravel.
I am trying to route to a controller, get some data out of the model and passing it to the view like this:

```
class PlayerController extends Controller{

 public function index(){
   $data['start'] = Player::allPlayer()->get();

   return View::make('pages.player')->with($data);
 }
}
```

now when i try to read the $data in the view. It says that it is undefined..

```
@if (isset($data))
{{'its there'}}
@else
{{'its not there'}}
@endif
```

what am i doing wrong? i tried to print_r the array in the controller. And it looks good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the variable by it's key:

```
class PlayerController extends Controller{

 public function index(){
   $data['start'] = Player::allPlayer()->get();

   return View::make('pages.player')->with($data);
 }
}
```

View:

```
@if (isset($start)) <--by key
{{'its there'}}
@else
{{'its not there'}}
@endif
```

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#creating-views)

Answer (score 0):

Even this should work

```
$post['hello'] = \App\Post::where('id','=',1)->get();
return view('test',compact('post'));
```

and in view

```
@if($post)
    {{$post['hello']}}
@else
    <p>Oops!</p>
@endif
```